# Cakephp return a rare json data with my custom query

Tags: php, json, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have this function in my controller:

```
public function estadisticas()
{
    $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $stmt = $conn->execute(
        'SELECT     c.nombre, 
       c.idcomplejo, 
       t.canchafk, 
       Count(*) AS cantidadturnos 
FROM       turno t 
INNER JOIN usuario u ON u.idusuario = t.usuariofk
INNER JOIN cancha ca ON t.canchafk = ca.idcancha 
INNER JOIN complejo c ON c.idcomplejo = ca.complejofk 
INNER JOIN ciudad cc ON cc.idciudad=c.ciudadfk
WHERE      u.escomplejo=0 
AND        cc.paisfk="1" 
AND        u.paisfk="1" 
AND        noasistio=0 
AND        fecha BETWEEN "2016-07-01" AND        "2016-07-30" 
GROUP BY   canchafk');


    $turnos = $stmt ->fetchAll('assoc');

    $this->set('turnos',$turnos);


}
```

I need to make custom query because is dificult to make it like cakephp said.
So the result is for each "turnos":

```
array(4) { ["nombre"]=> string(7) "Campnou" ["idcomplejo"]=> string(1) "1" ["canchafk"]=> string(1) "1" ["cantidadturnos"]=> string(2) "35" } 

array(4) { ["nombre"]=> string(6) "Uñazo" ["idcomplejo"]=> string(1) "3" ["canchafk"]=> string(1) "6" ["cantidadturnos"]=> string(2) "29" }
```

Like this the area 17 more arrays.

When I do this:

```
 <?php foreach ($turnos as $turno): ?>
        <tr>
            <br><?php var_dump($turno) ?></br>
            <td><?= h($turno['idComplejo']) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($turno['canchaFK']) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($turno['cantidadTurnos']) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The rows are empty, but cakephp show me 19 empty row (the total rows of the query) .In phpmyadmin the query works perfect.

So.. I have a problem try to showing the data from the json.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The arrays you are getting back have keys all in lower case, but in your view you are attempting to read things with mixedCase keys. Array keys are case-sensitive.